# How to display array data

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have output array like image
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu15E.png)

how to get data 'datamap'. help me please

Comment: In which language you want to extract the data? using Javascript or php?

Comment: If its a standard PHP array you can use $array['datamap']

Comment: my code like <?php echo $polygon['datamap'];?>
but output like 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'datamap'

Filename: admin-panel/map.php

Line Number: 1

Answer (score 0):

For JavaScript:

```
var json = ""; // your JSON string as a variable.
console.log(json.datamap);
```

For PHP:

```
$json = ""; // Same again
$jsonAsObject = json_decode($json);

echo $jsonAsObject->datamap;
```

Comment: I tried this, output Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\sorot\application\controllers\admin-panel\map.php

Comment: @RahmatSaepuloh Super sorry, was using JavaScript access modification instead of PHP... Edited the answer